# Custom printing area macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a macro that sets a print area to user selected areas of document. Basically there is a box next to a bunch of cells and if user ticks the box then the bunch of cells is included to the print area.
Here is my code so far:

```
Sub TestCellA1()

    Dim t As Integer, d As Integer
    t = 0
    d = 20
    Dim rng_per As Range
    Set rng_per = Range("A3:E328") 'prints whole document
    Dim rng1 As Range

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("F19")) = True Then
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range(rng_per)

    Else
        Do While t < 10
            If IsEmpty(Range("F" & d).Value) = True Then
                'MsgBox "Do not print"
            Else
                'MsgBox "Do print"
                ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = rng1
            End If
            t = t + 1
            d = d + 25

        Loop

    End If
End Sub
```

So far this works to the point where the actual work is supposed to be done. I planned that everytime when loop finds box ticked it adds that part of document to the print area. As a newbie with vba I have no idea how to add those areas to print area. Any ideas how to do it? Thanks in advance& have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

If you create and load a range into `rng_to_add`, the following will take the existing PrintArea and `Union` (append to) the `rng_to_add`:

```
' Going into this, you need to have declared a variable called rng_to_add
Dim rng_to_add As Range

' and loaded the range area you want to add to the PrintArea. This will
' be different for your particular situation.
Set rng_to_add = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C3")

' Referring to the current PageSetup of the Activesheet..
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

    ' Check if the PrintArea of above PageSetup is empty
    If .PrintArea = "" Then
        ' If so, set the PrintArea to the address of the Range: rng_to_add
        .PrintArea = rng_to_add.Address
    Else
        ' If not, set it to the address of a union (append) of the existing
        ' PrintArea's range and the address of the Range: rng_to_add
        .PrintArea = Union(Range(.PrintArea), rng_to_add).Address
    End If

' End the reference to the current PageSetup of the Activesheet
End With
```

---

So, for portability and/or integrating into your existing routines, you could create subroutines that manage the PrintArea like so:

```
Sub Clear_PrintArea()
    ' Set PrintArea to nothing
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
End Sub


Sub Add_range_to_PrintArea(rng_to_add As Range)

    ' Referring to the current PageSetup of the Activesheet..
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

        ' Check if the PrintArea of above PageSetup is empty
        If .PrintArea = "" Then
            ' If so, set the PrintArea to the address of the Range: rng_to_add
            .PrintArea = rng_to_add.Address
        Else
            ' If not, set it to the address of a union (append) of the existing
            ' PrintArea's range and the address of the Range: rng_to_add
            .PrintArea = Union(Range(.PrintArea), rng_to_add).Address
        End If

    ' End the reference to the current PageSetup of the Activesheet
    End With

End Sub
```

You could then **call** it like so:

```
Clear_PrintArea
Add_range_to_PrintArea Range("A1:C3")
Add_range_to_PrintArea Range("A7:C10")
Add_range_to_PrintArea Range("A13:C16")
```

Comment: As newbie to vba, could you comment your code more troughoutly?

Comment: Done. I've also given slightly more useful Subroutines that should make it easier for you to use.