# Adding multiple ranges to print area

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have twelve diffirent ranges that I may need to include to print area.
Here is part of my code so far:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    If 'condition is met' Then
        .PrintArea = Range(rng1)
        .PrintArea = Union(Range(.PrintArea), rng1).Address
    End If
    'more lines of like code
End With
```

There are several lines of code like this, I know this type of coding is not good practices, but I need to get over with this project quickly. 
My question is how to add needed ranges to the print area as now it seems to print only latest range set to print area?

Comment: Questions like these are comming around more often. Have a look here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489540/custom-printing-area-macro/50490615#50490615

Answer (score 2):

Print area is a `String`, not an `Object`. So you can write this:

```
.PrintArea = "$A$19:$J$32, $A$11:$J$17, $A$34:$J$38"
```

or you can work with `String` variables. If you stick on ranges, use `.Address` this way:

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rUni As Range
.PrintArea = rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address
```

or

```
Set rUni = Union(rng1, rng2)
.PrintArea = rUni.Address
```

Both latest examples result in a string like the one in the 1st example.

Interestingly, setting the print area in this scattered way results in printing all separate ranges to spearate pages. I do not know how to solve it.