# Fit the Print Range of the Union of Two Ranges to 1 Page Wide

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fit a print range to 1 page wide.

I'd like the **union** of two ranges in a sheet to be reduced to fit to 1 page wide (it may extend > 1 page vertically).

Currently, the second range (**MyRange2**) is always placed on a second page, even with reducing font sizes and column widths. Any insight why this page break consistently happens?

**Sheet layout:**

- Col headings are on row 5.
- Cols B, C, D and E contain a summary of data from other sheets.
- Col G contains totals (countif functions) of the data.
- Col F is hidden and contains temporary parsing/concatenations to help with the totals. I'm trying to hide or omit col F from the printout. Hence, the union of cols B through E -and- cols G and H.
- Col H contains the text labels for the totals in col G.
- Data in cols G and H will only ever range from H6 to H20.
- Data in cols B, C, D and E may include more than 20 rows with time (but not necessarily, and may be less than 20 rows).
- I use cells in row 1 as buttons linked to macros for printing, emailing, and deleting.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  
Application.Calculate
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then
    Me.Delete
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    GoToLast
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then

Dim lRow As Long
Dim dRow As Long
dRow = 20
lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim MyRange1 As Range, MyRange2 As Range, BigRange As Range

If lRow > dRow Then
    Set MyRange1 = Range("B3:E" & lRow)
    Set MyRange2 = Range("G3:H" & lRow)
Else
    Set MyRange1 = Range("B3:E" & dRow)
    Set MyRange2 = Range("G3:H" & dRow)
End If

Set BigRange = Application.Union(MyRange1, MyRange2)

Application.PrintCommunication = True 
With BigRange.Parent.PageSetup 'The Parent of Selection is the sheet.
    .PrintArea = BigRange.Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
Application.PrintCommunication = False
    
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
    
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
    'EmailSheet
    Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you copy the ranges to a new sheet and print that? I'm guessing the Union won't work when setting a print range.

Comment: Thanks SJR. Interestingly, this particular sheet is already a newly generated sheet from a "template" sheet. I suppose I could look into creating another temp sheet that is only used for printing, and then discard it after the print...

Comment: On the other hand perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742674/adding-multiple-ranges-to-print-area

Comment: Just noticed that that appears to print each range to a new page so it probably won't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help SJR. I suppose I could also just try using one range, but then hiding col F or making it's width 0. Accounting for the different lengths of the two ranges (B6:B__ vs. G6:H20) was what was initially perplexing me. For instance, B6:B13 (how to include and stop at row 20) vs. B6:B28 (how to extend beyond row 20 dynamically). There's probably an easier way than using a union...

Comment: You need to compare the last row of the 2 ranges and then find the max of those two and use that number to define the size of both.